# How to run an ordered-probit when your independent variable has one level?

Tags: r, categorical-data, ordered-probit

I just have a quick question. I am running an ordered probit regression in R. I have classified my variables into numeric or factor accordingly, but I am having issues with one of the independent variables that has only one level. The variable consists on selecting if you work in a Private Company. There is a separate variable to select if you work in a Non-private Company. How can I merge them into a variable with two levels?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you thought of merging them into a variable with two levels?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Try typing ?ifelse at the terminal for instructions.

Comment: I cant find a merging code with ?ifelse.

Comment: Try asking on R-Help or StackOverflow with a reproducible example as this is not really a statistical question now.

Comment: I am new at the website and haven't familiarised with it yet. I initially posted it on StackOverflow and was suggested to post it here. I would like to try merging the 2 variables into one with two levels, and see if that works for my regression. I tried asking on R-Help and it only shows how to merge two data frames. I couldn't find anything on Google either, and thought to give it a chance here.